# How to raise bootstrap button "over" a stretched link?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I'd like to put some content in a Bootstrap 4 card with a stretched link over it. I'd also like to include a button in this card which has a URL different to the stretched link.

Bootstrap's documentation says:

> Multiple links and tap targets are not recommended with stretched links. However, some position and z-index styles can help should this be required.

But I can't get it to work.

I've tried things like setting the z-index of the button to 5000, but it's still not clickable.

```html
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col align-self-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">This is a card</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">It has a button in it</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">How do I make the button rise up above the stretched link?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" role="button">Button Link</a>
                </div>
                <a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com" class="stretched-link"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[card example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psHKC.png)

I'd like to make it so the button is clickable without the stretched link covering it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the button to have the same z-index as the `stretched-link` will make the button clickable:

```css
.card .btn {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite solve my issue, but it got me on the road to a solution. I found that setting the z-index of the button like this didn't work, but if I instead put the button in a div and set the z-index of that div, it worked. It seems the z-index needs to be higher than 1 though. Setting it to 5000 worked 

Comment: Glad to be to help. The solution above worked for me in a similar case.

Answer (score 28):

I had to set `z-index` to a value > 1, *and* had to set `position: relative;` on the element to make it clickable on top of the `stretched-link`.

In your case, that means:

```
.card .btn {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Same solution works when using a `media` or `media-body` class, just be aware of the CSS selector

Answer (score 6):

Put a `<div>` around the button or link that is nested in a stretched link.
then give that div the following:

```
z-index:3;
position:relative;
```

Comment: adding these styles to the link itself was all I needed to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="stretched-link"` to button class as well. The code will be as following.

```
<div class="col-auto align-self-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary stretched-link" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" role="button">Button Link</a>
</div>
```